# AVL Tree not updating Height

Tags: python, python-3.x, avl-tree

I'm trying to implement an AVL tree in Python but for some reason its not making the proper rotations when I implement a large tree (Ive been using trees of size three for as my test cases but anything larger than three doesn't rotate properly) . I believe the problem is that it is not updating height properly, but I cant figure out why.
This is what I have so far:

```
class AVLTreeMap:

def __init__(self, key, value):
    self.key = key
    self.value = value
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.height = 1


def updateHeight(self):
    if self.right is None:
        right = -1
    else:
        right = self.right.height
    if self.left is None:
        left = -1
    else:
        left = self.left.height
    self.height = (1 + max(left, right))


def getBalance(self):
    if self is None:
        return 0
    if self.right is None:
        right = -1
    else:
        right = self.right.height
    if self.left is None:
        left = -1
    else:
        left = self.left.height
    return right - left

def put(self, key, value):
    if self is None:
        return AVLTreeMap(key, value)
    elif key < self.key:
        if self.left is None:
            self.left = AVLTreeMap(key, value)
        else:
            self.left.put(key, value)
            self.updateHeight()
            balance = self.getBalance()
            if balance <= -2:
                if key < self.left.key:
                    self.leftLeft()
                else:
                    self.leftRight()
    elif key == self.key:
        self.value = value
    elif key > self.key:
        if self.right is None:
            self.right = AVLTreeMap(key, value)
        else:
            self.right.put(key, value)
            self.updateHeight()

            balance = self.getBalance()
            if balance >= 2:
                if key < self.right.key:
                    self.rightLeft()
                else:
                    self.rightRight()

def rightRight(self):
    pivot = self.right
    pivot.left = self
    self = pivot
    self.right.updateHeight()
    self.updateHeight()

def leftLeft(self):
    pivot =self.left
    pivot.right = self
    self = pivot
    self.left.updateHeight()
    self.updateHeight()

def leftRight(self):
    pivot1 = self.left
    pivot2 = pivot1.right
    pivot3 = self
    self = pivot2
    self.left = pivot1
    self.right = pivot3
    self.left.updateHeight()
    self.right.updateHeight()
    self.updateHeight()

def rightLeft(self):
    pivot1 = self.right
    pivot2 = pivot1.left
    pivot3 = self
    self = pivot2
    self.left = pivot3
    self.right = pivot1
    self.left.updateHeight()
    self.right.updateHeight()
    self.updateHeight()
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: With your code in the question not correctly indented, given how important indenting is to the behaviour of Python code, I’m voting to close because you haven’t posted a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Please edit working code into your question.

Comment: And have you tried going from 3 to 4, 5, ... elements and observing the depth/rotation?